# Are there Illegal Logcat Tags?

Tags: android, logging, tags, character, logcat

I am the developer of Log This on Android Market, and a feature I am implementing requires me to use a URL parser (or write a string parser more like) that can parse a string for tags. I am not sure if I could use quotes to surround the tags, or if I can find an illegal character in the tags I would just use that.
Are there characters that are not allowed in Logcat Tags? Since it takes any string I'm going to assume that it takes anything, but I can't find anything on this subject.

Thanks,
Mgamerz

Answer (score 2):

Some that I can think of

- If the tag is > 23 characters long.
- If the tag used by the system already use isLoggable(). The documentation is not clear on this bit so you will have to check it for yourself. Basically it calls a native function, whose implementation may vary across OEMs.

Comment: I mean more like characters. That way, I can use that character in a link to separate out tags. Ill look into using quotes since I think there are no illegal characters.